# jQuery change method multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I would like to when I change `#town` and `#animal` value, then inputs background will be red.
My code is change the inputs background, when I change one input, but I would like to, if I change both input, after the code will be change the background color.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#town, #animal').on('change', function() {
            $('input').css('background', 'red');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="town">
<input type="text" id="animal">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "You would like to change the text input color to red onChange" I get the first part of your question I think. The second part is harder to read. Maybe you want to change the color only if BOTH inputs are changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxw5jrn4/)

```
$('#town, #animal').on('change', function() {
    if($.trim($('#town').val())!='' && $.trim($('#animal').val())!=''){
        $('input').css('background', 'red');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting it so that you want to wait until both inputs have changed, then that's pretty simple! :)

Simply, have two variables:

```
var townChanged = false;
var animalChanged = false;
```

Then, do two jQuery functions:

```
$('#town').on('change', function() {
    townChanged = true;
    if (animalChanged) {
        $('input').css('background', 'red');
    }
});

$('#animal').on('change', function() {
    animalChanged = true;
    if (townChanged) {
        $('input').css('background', 'red');
    }
});
```

Obviously you're going to want to clean it up a bit, but I hope that's a good start for you